# WPF Avalondock save layout to next start-up

Tags: c#, wpf, save, load, avalondock

I am using Avalondock tool and I think it is a great tool of using. It includes a lot of good features and easy to use.

I have used Avalondock a lot and i have implemented in my whole application, but one thing that would be insane to have is to remember the layout to next startup.

I have a userconfig that saves other configuration of the application, so i know how that work, but I need to know in details how to save and load the layout of floated panels.

I have read some other posts that I thought I could figure it out, but it became too hard, unfortunately.

I hope some sweet soul could give me an explanation about how this works and what I have to do step by step!

Good day

Best regard
Tobias

Comment: Have you tried using `DockingManager.SaveLayout` and `DockingManager.LoadLayout`?

Comment: No, where do I have to set it? You mean code behind?
or is it a property of the dockingmanager?

Comment: I can't find the property in my dockingmanager and I can't find it in code behind, if I declare my name of a dockingmanager and try to write the name.savelayout - it doesnt know the property :(

Comment: I use an older version of AvalonDock. Maybe it's changed in newer versions.

Comment: oh you are maybe right. I am using the latest version. You do not know how to implement it in the new?

Comment: Have you checked [SharpDevelop](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop) source to see how it's used there?

Comment: Has he made a project about loading panels' position? Because I can't find it in your link :/

Comment: SharpDevelop is an IDE, just like visual studio. It has a lot of functionality, but you have to dig deep to find something. You may check if SharpDevelop supports the behavior you need, and if it does - check how it's implemented. Sorry, can't give you concrete example.

Comment: Okay, I see. I will prefer to stay in Visual Studio though. I have seen some examples that have implemented it, but I can't figure it out and I need a little more detailed version of it. But thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: We use AvalonDock.Layout.Serialization.LayoutSerializer in combination with standard XmlSerializer to serialize the DockinManager's Layout.

Comment: Nice, can you explain me how to use it? It would be great :)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to serialize the layout using

> XmlLayoutSerializer

in

> Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.Serialization